# child theme automatically adds new page to top menu instead of only custom menu

Tags: menus

In my child theme I have top navigation and custom navigation (archive menu). When I add new page to archive menu, same page gets added to top nav. In the admin top nav doesn't show new page though,however, in the browser there's new page showing in top nav.

I unchecked 'Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu' in my top nav but it didn't help

```
  function archive_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('archive_menu',__( 'Archive' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'archive_menu' );
```

output in index.php

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu(

    array(
        'theme_location'=> 'archive_menu'
          
  )
);?>
```

Question: Is there a way to stop new page added to top nav and only have new page added to my archive nav.

**BACKEND ADMIN**

This is how my **custom menu** looks in the child theme admin

[image]

This is how my **primary menu** looks in the child theme admin

[image]

This is **primary (top) nav** in the browser (**red arrow shows 'archive' menu item which gets added automatically** even though I didn't add it in the admin).

[image]

Comment: " In the admin top nav doesn't show new page though,however, in the browser there's new page showing in top nav".  Does this mean that the WP menu manager in the back-end does not show the menu item that is visible on the front-end?  If so, add all of your `wp_nav_menu` and `register_nav_menu` to your question to help show the issue.

Comment: Because I am using child theme the only code I used is the above wp_nav_menu and register_nav_menu code for my custom menu. My understanding is that primary menu is  inherited  from parent

Comment: "Does this mean that the WP menu manager in the back-end does not show the menu item that is visible on the front-end? " Yes, the issue is when I add archive page to my custom menu in the admin, it gets added to the top nav when output in the browser however its not visible in the admin (I've added some screenshots to demonstrate the issue better).

Comment: That is very strange.  Have you looked at the slugs for the parent theme's menus?  Maybe there is some overlap there.

Comment: I just looked at the page slugs - they are the same both in parent and child theme http://localhost/mytheme-wp/blog/
http://localhost/mytheme-wp/about/
http://localhost/mytheme-wp/contact/