# contact form and WP loop

Tags: forms

I am trying to learn how to build contact form from scratch without plugin. I came across this tutorial
[https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/)

**I am not understanding why we need to put contact form code inside the loop as shown in the tutorial**. Out of curiousity I tried putting my code within page-contact.php without using the loop and it was rendered out correctly. I didn't start implementing php code yet.
I checked Codex about the_post and the_content tags and what they do within the loop. Say the_content pulls in from database the content of the page or post. So why my markup works without the loop and those tags?

**my current page-contact.php**

```
<?php get_header();?>

<main>
     
    <form  method="GET" action="form.html" class="contact">
     
     <div class="field-wrap">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required/>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
      <div class="message">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="25" required></textarea>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
      </div>  

      <button>Submit</button>
    
    </form>

   
</main>    


<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Your markup works because the template for your page contains that markup.  Keep in mind that PHP runs on the server before the page is rendered.  If you were to add a call to `the_content()` in your template, the CMS content would ALSO be displayed, along with the markup in your template.

Comment: It means the form html is rendered becuase the final document that the browser sees is an html document with html doctype which has nothing to do with WP loop. I get it now. thanks @jdm2112. would you be able to help me with my other question located here ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368929/child-theme-automatically-adds-new-page-to-top-menu-instead-of-only-custom-menu